# XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal (not strong with ajax)

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, tapestry

I know this question has been asked many times and from what i have researched on this error it appears that it happens because cross domain ajax is only allowed for JSONP, not XML. But i am having trouble finding where this call is being made so I can't exactly find where the problem is. Everything is working fine until I added the following code

```
@EventListener(targets="licensingStatus", events="onchange")
public void onLicenseStatusChange(IRequestCycle cycle){
    cycle.getResponseBuilder().updateComponent("licenceAuthRequiredDiv");
}
```

This is the component that the above code is updating

```
<div jwcid="licenceAuthRequiredDiv@Any">
      <span jwcid="@If" condition="ognl:company.licensingStatus == @com.fexco.wuams.valueobject.LicensingStatus@Pass && inApprovalMode()" renderTag="literal:false">
            <input jwcid="licensingApprovalDateRequired@DatePicker" disabled="ognl:disabled || isLicensingApprovalDateDisabled()"
            value="ognl:company.licensingApprovalDate" displayName="message:company.licensingApprovalDate" validators="validators:maxDateToday,required" />
     </span>
     <span jwcid="@Else" renderTag="literal:false">
            <input jwcid="licensingApprovalDate@DatePicker" disabled="ognl:disabled || isLicensingApprovalDateDisabled()"
            value="ognl:company.licensingApprovalDate" displayName="message:company.licensingApprovalDate" validators="validators:maxDateToday" />
      </span>
</div>
```

Using Firebug, when this is hit and moves through and a POST and GET requests are made and I get the following on the POST: `302 Moved Temporarily` and the GET request just hangs with the following: `XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{a752d6c1-8e61-4faf-9084-97124f7b3596} Line Number 1, Column 1:`

I know it is not much to work with so if ye need anymore information just ask, but can anyone shine some light on this for me?

Answer (score 4):

firefox complain when the content-type being returned is XML, but the contents are empty.

Comment: In my case response header showed "text/xml" but should have been "image/svg+xml", apache AddType image/svg+xml svg solved it for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the 302 redirecting you to another domain.

Answer (score 0):

I've this problem because of dataType parameter in jQuery request: [ajax response error(XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932930/ajax-response-errorxml-parsing-error-no-element-found-location-moz-nullprinci)?

Answer (score 0):

Check for unclosed XML tags,
firefox seems to report non-valid XML in existing file **SAME AS** non-existant xml file.
Chrome's inspector in Network panel reports more info: "error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document", and experienced developer should see this as unclosed tag problems.

Firefox reports: "Line Number 2, Column 1: ... XML Parsing Error: no root element found"