# ajax response error(XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i am unable to get the response from ajax. please guide me how to resolve this error, i am getting successful data return from the server i have checked it in **fiddle web debugger** and still ajax is showing error.
***XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{6b0a1ac2-50ab-4053-9f71-8ae49202288d} Line Number 1, Column 1:***

```
            $j.ajax({

            type:"POST",
            url:'http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit',
            data: 'Celsius=12',
            crossDomain:true,
            async: false,
            success:function(response)
            {
                alert("Success Full Done"+response.string);
            },
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
 xhr.overrideMimeType( 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8' );
}

        });
```

Comment: check this link: http://tharindumathew.com/2012/05/16/xml-parsing-error-in-firebug/

Comment: the link is now at: http://mackiemathew.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/xml-parsing-error-in-firebug/

Answer (score 6):

I've this problem with request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    dataType : "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (data) {
         ...
    }
});
```

Accept header in request is:

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

Response status is 200, but browser detect error and no success callback called

Fixed by remove dataType : "json":

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    contentType: "application/json",
    ...
```

The only difference that accept header in request changed to:

```
Accept  */*
```

But now success callback is called.

Answer (score 3):

Add the "beforeSend" function into your AJAX call to override the acceptable response mime type.

Refer to the jQuery.ajax() documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

As of jQuery 1.5.1, the jqXHR object also contains the overrideMimeType() method (it was available in jQuery 1.4.x, as well, but was temporarily removed in jQuery 1.5). The .overrideMimeType() method may be used in the beforeSend() callback function, for example, to modify the response content-type header:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
  }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
  });
```

And:

**Data Types**

Different types of response to $.ajax() call are subjected to different kinds of pre-processing before being passed to the success handler. The type of pre-processing depends by default upon the Content-Type of the response, but can be set explicitly using the dataType option. If the dataType option is provided, the Content-Type header of the response will be disregarded.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I made `GET` `XMLHttpRequest` call.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', '/exampleServlet', false);
req.send(null);
```

It was fixed by setting  ContentType on the HttpServletResponse.

```
 response.setContentType("text/plain");
```

Comment: you are right, I did it from the servlet, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This error may be caused due to two reason. One is when getting no response from java backend and other is when their is no @ResponseBody in java Controller method.

Answer (score 0):

I added ContentType to ResponseEntity and problem solved. Try to add a valid ContentType to your controller response:

`ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem with a simple request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: something,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

In my case, this was a fire-and-forget scenario - I don't care about the response. To solve it, it was a case of changing the server-side code to correctly return a `204: No content` status code, instead of returning `200: OK`.